# Check emitted event with BN

Tags: truffle, testing, truffle-test, bignumber, truffle-assertions

I'm currently testing events that include numeric values:

```js
const level = new BN(1);
truffleAssert.eventEmitted(tx, 'EventName', {level});
```

As you can see, the `level` variable is a `BN`, and holds the correct value, I've already checked that. However two `BN` objects seem not to be equal when comparing through `eventEmitted`.

I know I can do it in the following way:

```js
const level = new BN(1);
truffleAssert.eventEmitted(tx, 'EventName', e => e.level.toString() === level.toString());
```

However this second way is less intuitive, longer to write, harder to maintain and definitely much dirtier.

Do you guys know if there's a workaround to make this work using objects rather than filter functions?

Answer (score 2):

Actually never mind, I just found the solution, which is definitely not very intuitive. I leave it here in case it can help someone.

```js
const level = web3.utils.toBN(1);  // <------ we must use this function
truffleAssert.eventEmitted(tx, 'EventName', {level});  // now this works
```

So just using `web3.utils.toBN` suffices.